# How to store onclick value of a jsp page in session?

Tags: java, jsp, session, onclick

[image]

```html
<c:forEach items="${friendList}" var="friend">
  <tr>
    <th id="id">${friend.id}</th>
    <td id="name"><a href="ProfilePageRedirectServlet" onclick=<%session.setAttribute( "userName", ${friend.name});%>>${friend.name}</a></td>
    <td id="dob">${friend.dateOfBirth}</td>
    <td id="age">${friend.age }</td>
    <td><a href="DeleteFriendServlet?id=${friend.id }">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I am trying to store the onclick value in session in jsp.

[image]

Comment: you cannot store like that  instead on click of `a` tag call ajax and send value which you need to store to backend .

Comment: You cannot call Java code in a JavaScript onclick handler. The Java code in a JSP is executed at server side to generate the response (HTML/JavaScript). The JavaScript code is executed inside the browser after receiving the HTML/JavaScript. As Swati suggested in the onclick handler you can call the server via AJAX. Or you submit the whole page. But the code in the onclick handler should be JavaScript and is executed at the client side. The session only exists at server side. So you have to call the server in one form or another.